# Update Comments state in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, crud, redux-toolkit

I'm creating a CRUD project with React and Redux toolkit and the problem is I can't update Comments after creating a new one.

I structured Comment Slice like that:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import commentsService from "./commentService";

const initialState = {
  comments: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

export const createComment = createAsyncThunk(
  "api/newcomment",
  async (commentData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await commentsService.createComment(commentData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

export const getAllComments = createAsyncThunk(
  "api/comments",
  async (PostId, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    return await commentsService.getAllComments(PostId, token);
  }
);

export const deleteComment = createAsyncThunk(
  "api/:id",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await commentsService.deleteComment(id, token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

export const commentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "comment",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createComment.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(createComment.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.comments = state.comments.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(createComment.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getAllComments.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getAllComments.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        const comments = state.comments.filter(
          (comment) => comment.PostId === action.payload.PostId
        );
        if (comments.length === 0) {
          state.comments.push(action.payload);
        }
      })
      .addCase(getAllComments.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(deleteComment.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(deleteComment.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.comments = state.comments.filter(
          (comment) => comment.id !== action.payload.id
        );
      })
      .addCase(deleteComment.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

And CardPost where I dispatch comments:

```
const CardPost = ({ post }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const PostId = post.id;

  const { comments, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.comments
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      console.log(message);
    }
    dispatch(getAllComments(PostId));
  }, [dispatch, PostId, isError, message]);

//// Show Comments
   <div>
              <div>
                <FormComment PostId={PostId} />
              </div>
              <div>
                {comments.length > 0 ? (
                  <div className="comments">
                    {comments.map((id) => (
                      <div key={id}>
                        <CardComment post={post} />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <Typography>No Comment..</Typography>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
```

When there are several comments on a Post that are displayed and I create a new one, it shows me the message "No comment.." but all the messages appear well when the page is refreshed.
Where did I make it wrong?
Is it the .addCase that I built wrong and the state is not updated or is it the useEffect dispatch?

Comment: Can you debug it first?